# Lua obfuscation issue

Tags: lua, obfuscation, decompiling

I have tried to decompile one of Lua script just for learning purposes, and I got the original code however the code was obfuscated like below:

```
local L0_0, L1_1, L2_2, L3_3, L4_4, L5_5, L6_6, L7_7, L8_8, L9_9, L10_10, L11_11, L12_12, L13_13, L14_14, L15_15, L16_16, L17_17, L18_18, L19_19, L20_20, L21_21, L22_22, L23_23, L24_24, L25_25, L26_26, L27_27, L28_28, L29_29
L0_0 = require
L1_1 = "comm.NetworkClock"
L0_0 = L0_0(L1_1)
L1_1 = require
L2_2 = "comm_ads.fullscreenAds"
L1_1 = L1_1(L2_2)
L2_2 = require
L15_15 = L14_14.init
L15_15()
L15_15 = L4_4.log
L16_16 = "IN main"
L15_15(L16_16)
function L15_15()
  local L0_30, L1_31
end
print = L15_15
```

Is there any way to recover these code to reach the original one?

Comment: no and even if the code doesn't make too much sense and causes errors

Comment: Yes, because I just added a snapshot of the code, not all the file.

Answer (score 2):

Can you get back to the **original** source? No, not likely.

Source code is optimized to be read by humans, byte code is optimized to be read by machines. Compiling usually results in a one-way conversion where information required to restore the original source is lost.

Best bet at this point is to simplify it by hand and a bunch of find & replace once you identify what a variable or function actually does.

If you did find (or build) a tool to simplify the decompiled source code to be more human-readable, it still would not really be reproducing the original source code.